# Update project from EF 4.1 to EF 5.x

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1

Can someone explain how I can update an existing project using EF 4.1 to use the latest EF 5.x in Visual Studio 2010?

I have already used NuGet to download the EF 5.x code.  Is it simply a matter of replacing the reference of 'EntityFramework' to the one from EF 5.x?  If so where is the EF 5.x code stored on my local drive?  With EF 4.1 there was a directory called 'Microsoft Entity Framework 4.1' but I don't see anything like that for EF 5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download the package from NuGet it will add the references for you, if you want to locate the binaries (although you shouldn't have to) they can be found in the /packages folder in the root of your solution.

You can double-check the reference has been added by expanding the 'References' solution folder as normal.

Comment: Well, not sure what I did but now the reference is updated to EF 5.0.  I did restart VS after downloading the package but that didn't update it.  I also went back into NuGet (after restarting VS) and made VS re-get the EF 5.x package and even though it said it was already installed, doing a re-get of the package appears to have updated the reference.  Marked this answer as it did answer the question of where the package is installed.